# Why would the it be/being the same?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> You may ask why would the color on the same side of each stick being the same?

Is it right to use **being** in this sentence? Or should I use the **be** instead of **being**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use *being* here.

The construction is

> You may ask [why **would** [the color on the same side of each stick] **be** the same].

Modals like *would* always always always take the base form of the verb (sometimes called the infinitive), not any other form. (Sometimes the verb in question is another helping verb, as in "would be going" or "would have gone", but the verb governed by the modal is still in its  base form.)